# MySQL Transaction Patterns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, transactions

I'm stuck on how I should fix this problem involving MySQL transactions. The scenario is complex, but an analogous situation is as follows: I have a post table, with tags bound to these posts through a one to one relationship (via a binding table). That's three tables.

What I want to do is "update" a post's body, and I do this by creating a copy (we have a requirement to see revision history). So I need to make a copy of the post, insert it back into the posts table, and, critically, move all the tag bindings from the old post to the new one. Subsequently, I then parse the new post for new tag bindings and bind them via the binding table to the new post.

I need to ensure that all these steps complete, otherwise I will lose integrity and consistency within the database. Wrapping these in a MySQL transaction at REPEATABLE_READ isolation level causes a fundamental problem: the updates to the tag binding table are NOT accessible to any of the operations further down the chain.

That is, I move all the tag bindings from post A to post B, and then insert new bindings to post A. This can fail, because "duplicate tag bindings" will appear even though in reality they have moved (at REPEATABLE READ, the INSERT/SELECT statements are reflecting the state of the database before the transaction!)

I'm not sure how to guarantee consistency and be able to solve this problem. I could drop the isolation level to READ_COMMITTED, but dirty reads can appear and transaction isolation is lost.

Is this something a design pattern can solve? I appreciate any advice! I'm using MySQL, PHP (PDO connectors).

Cheers,
Adrian

Comment: Could you show structures of these thee tables ? And to do the question more concrete, would you show also the transaction code ?